# Kivy: Limit size of dropdown

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

Is there any way to limit the size of DropDown box? I would like to limit it to size of maybe 4-5 choices, instead of having it running all the way to the edge of screen.I started experimenting with DropDown as Spinner didn't have any interface for doing so.. Both elements in my use case should do the same, but it seemed like DropDown would provide more flexibility as I had to compose the picker myself. Unfortunately, changing hint or size for DropDown seems to do nothing, as the list still gets fully expanded.

Here is code for what I got now:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

class DropDownPicker(Button):
    def __init__(self, listOfChoices, **kwargs):
        result = super(DropDownPicker, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.text='Select'

        pickerList = DropDown()

        for item in listOfChoices:
            choiceButton = Button(text=item, size_hint_y=None, height=25)
            choiceButton.bind(on_release=lambda btn: pickerList.select(btn.text))
            pickerList.add_widget(choiceButton)

        self.bind(on_release=pickerList.open)
        pickerList.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self, 'text', x))

        pickerList.size_hint_y = None
        pickerList.size = (0, 100)

        return result

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        choices = []
        for x in range(50):
            choices.append("Choice " + str(x))
        return DropDownPicker(choices)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Those last 2 lines before `return` should be doing the trick, but they aren't. I also tried to specify this in DropDown constructor, however I changed this because at that time there might have been problem that final size is not yet known. This wasn't the case as it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modyfing `size_hint_y` property, but not to `None` (it's default) but to the decimal value, for example:

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

dropdown = DropDown()
dropdown.size_hint_y = 0.5
for index in range(100):
    btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
    dropdown.add_widget(btn)

mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

Comment: I thought that all elements have size_hint_y = 1 by default. Your solution works though so I'll start from here. It might be problem that I'm having this dropdown in popup window, will try to debug it more now that I know it does work sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: You can see that `size_hint_y` is setted inside `DropDown` constructor in source code: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/dropdown.py#L183

Comment: Yes that now makes sense why nothing happened, although they quite broke the convention with that, resulting in no possible way to set fixed size (the 0.5 value is percentage of free space so when window size changes, this will also). But for now it's good enough and I can live whit it.